# kendoui - popup editing - v 2012.3.1114

Tags: kendo-ui

When I insert a new record in popup mode, for some fields does not change the status (red triangle), the value is not updated and the data is transmitted "empty" to the webservice.
If I press "backspace", the field changes status to "modified" (red triangle) and sent to the webservice.
In the "2012.2.814" worked well.
I attach a sample program (rename png in htm)
Thank you.
Michele.

Comment: or even show the code on jsfiddle / jsbin...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the MVC wrappers, make sure you've updated the DLL. In either case, make sure you've updated all the .js files to 2012.3.1114. In our projects, we will go through the process of deleting all the kendo*.js files in the Scripts directory then replacing them with the latest versions. That also takes care of the occasionally deprecated js file. Check your layout and make sure you aren't calling them in the wrong order (if you're using MVC-4 I highly recommend using CDN and/or the bundling option).
Also update your Content and check a couple of browsers (Chrome's developer tools, Fiddler, Firebug as well) to see if there are any errors/warnings that might help explain it.
Finally, Kendo now supports jQuery 1.8.2 - the previous versions required jQuery 1.7. I found that moving to jQuery 1.8.2 gave a modest performance boost and resolved some grouping issues I was having with the Grid component.